# How to invert the bits of a Scapy packet (complement of a packet)

Tags: python, scapy, packet

Say I have a packet that contains fields that are all hex values. How can I define a function that returns a packet where all of the hex values for the fields in the packet are inverted? Here is what I have so far:

```
def complementPacket(pkt):
    '''
        Function: complementPacket
        Purpose: Takes a packet as an input and inverts all bits in the packet.
        Return: Inverted packet of same structure as the input packet
    '''
    retPkt = pkt
    while(pkt): # iterate through the packets
        for field in pkt.fields_desc:
            print(fmtToLen(field.fmt)) # converts scapy field.fmt to the number of bits for that field type
            # invert bits, assign to retPkt
        pkt = pkt.payload
    return retPkt
```

The only solution I can think of would be to iterate through the packet and construct a new packet by taking the complement of all the fields. Is there a better way to do this?

**Given a packet, P, with hex (binary) values, I want to return ~P.**

---

Example:

```
def customPacket(Packet):
    name = "myPacket"
    fields_desc = [XByteField("data", 1)]

pkt = customPacket()
```

`pkt.show()` will output that the value of 'data' is 0x1

```
complementedPkt = complementPacket(pkt)
```

`complementedPkt.show()` will output that the value of 'data' is 0xE

(0x1 = 0001, ~0001 = 1110, 1110 = 0xE)

Comment: you can use `str()` to convert the packet to a raw string, then there are trivial ways to invert that string like xoring all the bytes with 0xff

Comment: This might be a dumb question but after I do that, how would I get it back into a Scapy packet object?

Comment: you CAN create a packet with mostly whatever data you want, but some values cannot be changed no matter how hard you try, like length fields... why do you want it in packet form? to send it? depending on the type of packet it might literally be impossible for the os to send it

Comment: Yeah I want to send it.

Comment: So far, your comment is the closest to a possible answer. Could you please post it as an answer so if it works I can choose it as correct? (maybe with a little more detail) @AntiMatterDynamite

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood your question, you just need to invert the packet, right ? In that case:

```
class Packet(object):
""" Class represents a Packet object """

# _fields - is a list containing all hexa values, e.g. 0xff, 0x14 
def __init__(self,vals):
    self._fields = list(vals)
'''
def __iter__(self):
    for field in self._fields:
        yield field '''

''' 
Function mimics  bit (~) inversion. For instance, 
1. 0xA4 -> ~1010 0100 -> 0101 1011 -> 0x5B
Param:
  mask -> number of bytes'''
def invert(self, mask=2):
    for (i, f) in zip(range(len(self._fields)), self._fields):
        #check is needed for Ox0000 value(s)
        if f.lower().lstrip('0x') == '':
            xor = int('0', 16) ^ int('f'*mask, 16)
            self._fields[i] = hex(xor)
        else:
            xor = int(f.lower().lstrip('0x'), 16) ^ int('f'*mask, 16)
            self._fields[i] = hex(xor)

def __str__(self):
    return ", ".join(x for x in self._fields)

def __repr__(self):
    return ", ".join(x for x in self._fields)
```

To test this you have to create a Packet object and populate is with data. You can try this:

```
p1 = Packet([hex(x) for x in range(32)])
p2 = Packet([hex(x) for x in range(32,64)])
p3 = Packet([hex(x) for x in range(64,128)])

print("Original packet(p1): \n", p1)
p1.invert()
print("Packet after inversion(p1):\n",p1)
#----------------------------------------------
print("Original packet(p2): \n", p2)
p2.invert()
print("Packet after inversion(p2):\n",p2)
#----------------------------------------------
print("Original packet(p3): \n", p3)
p3.invert(3)
print("Packet after inversion(p3):\n",p3)
```